# Retrieving related data using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I have an MVC app using EF code first. I add a user to the system and enter pension details, part of this is a dropdown linked to a model called PensionBenefitLevel. This is the model -

```
[Key]
public int PensionBenefitLevelID { get; set; }
public string DisplayText { get; set; }
public int EmployeePercentage { get; set; }
public int EmployerPercentage { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Pension> Pension { get; set; }
```

When registered I have the PensionBenefitLevelID that came from the dropdown, but in my controller I was to peform a calculation using the EmployerPercentage value that is related to that ID. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Do I need to create a variable in the controller and use a linq query to get that value back? I've not been able to find any examples of something similar so if you could point me to one that would be great too.

Comment: What calculation do you need to perform?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get back the entity corresponding to `PensionBenefitLevelID` and perform a calculation on the `EmployerPercentage` field.

Since you haven't mentioned what pattern you are using with EF (repository, unit of work, etc.) I can only give you a general answer:

```
var entity = [Your DB Context].[Your Entity].GetById(pensionBenefitLevelID);

if(entity != null)
{
    [Calculation]
}
```